# Change icon pack in KDE Plasma

Tags: kubuntu, kde, icons, trash

I use KUbuntu and I use Breeze theme, I like it, but I would like to use trash icon from Ubuntu 16 (Unity) which looks like this (I have it):

[image: Trash icon]

So I created folder `Breeze_tomsk` (I copied original Breeze icons and replaced trash icon) in `~/.icons/` folder, and I cannot change my icon pack, because in Plasma settings I don't see my icon pack, where is problem?

[image: KDE Plasma settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In KDE plasma 5 the correct directory is ~/.local/share/icons

As the comment state below, you maybe need to edit the `Name=` line in `~/.local/share/icons/Name/index.theme`

Comment: You could also mention that it maybe useful to edit the `Name=` line in `~/.local/share/icons/.../index.theme`.

Comment: Thank you :) It works now.